# Can the present perfect continuous say anything about the future?

Tags: meaning, tense

The present perfect continuous is a tense that relates a past action to the present, but does it say anything about the future?

I have read that the present perfect continuous often suggests that something said in the present perfect continuous that has just stopped may start again in the future.

For example: "It has been raining, the street is wet." If the rain has stopped it will probably rain again in the near future. Is this true?

Because to me it means that until recently it was raining and as a consequence the street is wet in the present. It says nothing about whether it will rain again soon.

Comment: The present perfect continuous says **nothing** about the future.

Comment: @Michael Harvey Is what I have written above correct?

Comment: I just said so.

Comment: It says nothing *explicit* about the future, but it doesn't deny anything explicit about the future either. In the right context, it could easily imply something that doesn't appear to be stopping. If I hear *It's miserable out! It's been raining all day, and the street is wet* without any additional information, I would probably assume that it is *still* raining, and that it will likely continue to rain for at least a little amount of time. The syntax does not say that (and I could be wrong in my assumption), but the general context of the sentence does suggest it.

Comment: Yes, I was about to say that a statement expressed in the pp continuous may lead us to assumptions or expectations about the future, e.g. it has been raining all day; I expect that the river will be swollen, but these come from common sense or knowledge independent of the statement.

Comment: Note that the present perfect continuous on its own does not mean that whatever you describe is no longer currently happening. *The baby has been crying all morning **and won't stop**.* The additional information makes it clear that it's still happening, but the verb form itself doesn't preclude that from being the case, even if the additional information is *not* provided. And if something is currently happening while you utter the sentence, it's extremely unlikely that it will stop right after—so it suggests at least something about the future in the short term.

Comment: @Jason Bassford I understand your example, but I specifically meant "It has been raining" when the rain has recently stopped and without "all day".

Comment: @anouk My point is that the sentence *it has been raining* does ***not*** mean that the rain has recently stopped. In order for that meaning to be explicit, you have to add that as additional information (*but has now stopped*). Without any qualification, the current state of affairs is unknown. But if you *do* add that additional information, then see the first comment here …

Comment: @Jason Bassford don't you mean "but has stopped"?

Comment: @anouk *But has stopped* and *but has **now** stopped* have essentially the same meaning. My use of *now* is for emphasis—and also because *it has been raining, but has stopped* is not idiomatic. Normally, the *now* (or something like *recently*) is added (even though, syntactically, they mean pretty much the same thing).